# Date pattern in arabic

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat

hello guys I have a web service that returns the date as a string ex: 2016-4-10.
my android application is bilingual (Arabic and English), when it's in English I;m able to transform the date into the following pattern Tuesday, September 2016
but I'm failing in changing it when in Arabic to:
الثلاثاء, تشرين أول 2016
please help.

English case:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d");
        Date date3 = null;
        try {
            date3 = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM yyyy");
        String format = sdf.format(date3);
        System.out.print("Result: " + format);
        holder.date.setText(format);
```

Arabic case:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar", "KW");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d",locale); //doesnt work
        Date date3 = null;
        try {
            date3 = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM yyyy");
        String format = sdf.format(date3);
        System.out.print("Result: " + format);
        Log.wtf("result",format);
        holder.date.setText(format);
```

Comment: Glad you found your answer. As a tip for future questions, instead of just "_I'm failing in changing it when in Arabic_" you should clearly show _how_ it's failing: exactly what you are getting and what you want (I'm assuming "الثلاثاء, تشرين أول 20" is what you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it worked !!!

Arabic case:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d");
        Date date3 = null;
        try {
            date3 = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM yyyy",locale);
        String format = sdf.format(date3);
        System.out.print("Result: " + format);
        Log.wtf("result",format);
        holder.date.setText(format);
        //holder.date.setText(date);
```